# Safari force quites on typing the three letters "sac" on search bar

Tags: mac, safari, crash

You might not believe me. So I have attached a video link below. I tried clearing history and restarting the computer, etc. It doesn't work. Is the combination "sac" something for quitting the app?

[Google drive link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B-v7erlvhnOWcmhHN0xQeUQzMFU)

This is not the first time my browsers are behaving weird on my Mac. A month ago, my Mac started behaving weird. Whenever I tried to upload something on any browser, the whole laptop crashed. Every click on my trackpad was counted twice, iTunes would crash, adobe reader would stop working etc.... And now, another issue has popped up. I had to get my laptop restored to fix the previous issues. Please don't make me do it again.

Comment: I have some ideas for you to try. In Safari Preferences/Search, turn off "Include search engine suggestions", and the other check boxes, esp. "Preload Top Hit in the background."  In Safari/Bookmarks menu, Open Bookmarks, then on that page, type "sac" in the upper right search field. Delete any bookmarks found. I see you have Adobe Reader opening PDFs. Try changing your default PDF reader to Preview. In the Finder, right click a PDF, select "Open with", select "other", check "Always Open With", then select Preview. You will have to clear history again after this stuff.